# Using tapply after convert a data.frame to a data_frame (dplyr) - R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am using the dplyr and nicheRover packages to do some calculations

```
require(nicheROVER)
data(fish)

require(dplyr)

fish <- fish %>% group_by(species)

# other things I do with dplyr

clrs <- c("black", "red", "blue", "orange")  # colors for each species

fish.par <- tapply(1:nrow(fish), fish$species, function(ii) niw.post(nsamples = 10, 
                                                                     X = fish[ii, 2:4]))

# format data for plotting function

fish.data <- tapply(1:nrow(fish), fish$species, function(ii) X = fish[ii, 2:4])

niche.plot(niche.par = fish.par, niche.data = fish.data, pfrac = 0.05,  
           col = clrs, xlab = expression("Isotope Ratio (per mil)"))
```

This gives

```
Error in density.default(niche.data[[ii]][, ci], n = ndens) : 
  argument 'x' must be numeric
```

Then if I check with str() it results in a tbl_df

```
str(fish.data[[1]][,1]) 

Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  69 obs. of  1 variable:  $ D15N: num  12.2 11.2 12.1 11.2 12.1 ...
```

how can I change the `tapply` command above so that the columns are num like this

```
str(fish.data[[1]][,1])

num [1:69] 12.2 11.2 12.1 11.2 12.1 ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
fish.data <- tapply(1:nrow(fish), fish$species, 
             function(ii) X = as.data.frame(fish[ii, 2:4]))

niche.plot(niche.par = fish.par, niche.data = fish.data, pfrac = .1,
           iso.names = expression(delta^{15}*N, delta^{13}*C, delta^{34}*S),
           col = clrs, xlab = expression("Isotope Ratio (\u2030)"))
```

Note that I took the `niche.plot` command straight out of the examples of `niche.plot`. Your line produced a separate and seemingly unrelated error.

It seems that `niche.plot` is doing some subsetting at some point, expecting a vector or singular value as output. `tbl_df`'s do not reduce to vectors if subsetting a single row or column though, unlike standard `data.frames`, and this seems to cause the problem. In the above code, I have just reconverted the output into a standard dataframe.